# How do I center an image in a circle around it?

Tags: html, css

How do I center an image in a circle around it? The circle should then **lie behind the picture** and **only frame it**.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <img src="../../assets/img/img.png" alt="" class="showslide">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
    margin-top: 5%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
    
.showslide {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: expected output and current output pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to keep the circle div as a sibling of the image?
Because if you put the image inside the circle div, your code it´s already working:

```css
.circle {
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.showslide {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
    <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/account-avatar-profile-human-man-user-30448.png" alt="" class="showslide">
</div>
```

I've removed the z-index (not needed in this case) and changed the border color to black.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      color: #262e2e;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      background: #f5f8fa;
      padding: 40px 0px;
    }

    .image-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
```

```html
  <h4>Center Image</h4>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img
        src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/kiev-ukraine-march-31-2015-260nw-275940803.jpg"
        width="100"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish here but as far as I understood, ur trying to make the frame unclickable. First of all, you can't keep the frame behind the picture because then the image gets in front of it and keeps it hidden.

`pointer-events: none;`


Set this for the frame and it should be good.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I center an image in a circle around it?

One approach would be to apply two CSS properties to the `<img>`:

- a `border`
- an `outline`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.my-image {
  width: 144px;
  height: 144px;
  border: 18px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<img class="my-image" src="https://picsum.photos/132/132" alt="My Picture">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
      color: #262e2e;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      background: #f5f8fa;
      padding: 40px 0px;
    }

    .image-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    }
</style>
<body>
<h4>Center Image</h4>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="image-container"
        src="i.jpg"
        width="100"
      />
    </div>
    <input type="file" >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).